# Why is the same MOSFET model give very different output for this circuit?

Tags: mosfet

I have [this](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF) MOSFET and as you see below it works fine when I try as inverting switch :

[image]

But when I try this on breadboard with three 2N7000 only one of them is like the simulation. If I try with the other two the Vout becomes only zero to 4V instead of zero to 5V.

What could be happening here? Everything is the same I just replace the MOSFETs from the same package.

Here is the breadboard wiring of this circuit:
[image]
(yellow is gate input, brown is Vsupply)

And below is scope screen for the same circuit with 5V and 4V output:

[[image]]

[image: s very diffent outputenter image description here]

Note: I also tried with R1 100 Ohm, nothing changes.

Comment: Is your gate drive voltage positively biased maybe at 1 volt ? If it is, some of the devices won’t turn off correctly.

Comment: I use this module for gate drive voltage https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/adalm2000.html and set it as 0 5V 5Hz pulse train and checked it with scope and it shows 0 5.2V.

Comment: Very odd. What does the dodgy MOSFET drain voltage look like when the gate input is shorted to source?

Comment: Electrostatic damage is a possibility unless you are using proper ESD technique. Replace the transistor in a failing circuit with a brand new one taking proper care to ground yourself, the breadboard andall tools first.

Comment: @Andyaka When I do that two of them shows 4V and one shows 5V drain voltage.

Comment: Faulty MOSFETs is my reasonable guess. Idss is the data sheet parameter that suggests that no more than 1 uA will flow into the drain when Vgs is zero volts.

Comment: Where did you get your MOSFETs? You appear to be a hobby/younger student. I know that often people like you (I was the same) got components from amazon or ebay or other online sites. Unfortunatly, they often contain faulty/rebadged/etc parts.

Comment: I'd guess counterfeit or ESD damage/